# Error "aapt.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

When I build a Visual Studio solution on Xamarin Android, I get the error:

> "aapt.exe" exited with code 1.

but I still can deploy the app and run the app.

What is the cause of this error?

[image]

Comment: Upload a complete diagnostic build output to your answer. My initial guess would be naming a resource incorrectly.

Comment: I think it was image name problem for example i have image in xamarin.Driod snl res\drawable\logo-flexi1.png. file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when I add an image that has in name "-".

Change the image name and the problem will disappear.